# Importar datos desde un Csv guardarlos en la bd junto a otros datos de entrada Laravel,

Tags: laravel, csv, laravel-excel

Estoy tratando de importar datos desde un csv, y a la vez quiero colocar un campo fecha ingresado por el usuario, para los datos del csv estoy usando Laravel excel

aquí mi modelo:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UsoSuelo extends Model
{
    protected $table = "uso_suelos";

    protected $fillable = ['fecha','cod_pais', 'cod_fundo','nom_fundo','cod_uso_suelo','dsc_uso_suelo','cod_rodal','cod_especie','dsc_especie','ano_plantacion','cod_esquema','dsc_esquema','dsc_restriccion_suelo','sup_ha','cod_z_cpino','cod_z_prod','cod_sz_prod','cod_sz_prod','dsc_sz_prod','id_area_us','region','comuna'
];
}
```

aqui mi controlador

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use App\Imports\UsosSueloImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use App\UsoSuelo;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UsoSueloController extends Controller
{
    public function showForm()
    {
        return view('upload');
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {   
    //dd($request->all());   
    //$fecha = $request->fecha;
    //dd($fecha); 
    $usoSuelo = new UsoSuelo();
    $usoSuelo->fecha = $request->fecha;

    Excel::import(new UsosSueloImport,request()->file('archivoCsv'));   
    $usoSuelo->save();     
    return view('mensaje');
}
}
```

aqui mi vista

```
@extends('layouts.base')
@section('content')

        <div class="card-header">
            Importar Archivo Csv
        </div>
            <form action="{{url('/upload')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <input type="file" name="archivoCsv" class="form-control">
                <br>
                <input class="form-control" type="date" name="fecha">
                <br>
                <button class="btn btn-success">Subir</button>

            </form>
@endsection
```

si saco el campo fecha de mi base de datos, y solo me dedico a subir el csv funciona bien, pero al colocar un nuevo campo e intentar guardarlo me genera el siguiente error:

```
LSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'fecha' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `uso_suelos` (`cod_pais`, `cod_fundo`, `nom_fundo`, `cod_uso_suelo`, `dsc_uso_suelo`, `cod_rodal`, `cod_especie`, `dsc_especie`, `ano_plantacion`, `cod_esquema`, `dsc_esquema`, `dsc_restriccion_suelo`, `sup_ha`, `cod_z_cpino`, `cod_z_prod`, `cod_sz_prod`, `dsc_sz_prod`, `id_area_us`, `region`, `comuna`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (90, 101, adsa, 1031, adsa, 199703, 1, dsada, 1997, 16, adsa, SIN adsa, 154.42, 6, 1, 3, asd, 132, 8, asd, 2020-01-16 12:32:30, 2020-01-16 12:32:30))
```

les dejo mi migración 
http://prntscr.com/qojghq
y la migración cuando añadi el nuevo campo
http://prntscr.com/qojgvn

Uso laravel 5.8 y laravel excel 3.1